# Adding multiple items to shopping cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a little clothing website and I ran into an issue while hooking up the cart.

Now, I have managed to add a "Add To Cart" button that sends the required information to the cart itself. But at the moment you can only send one product, and it only displays one product.

I had a similar issue while working with another feature of the website, but that was solved with just creating a new object and using the spread operator. I tried doing this to the cart as well, but didn't get anything to work.

I am not 100% sure how I shall be able to add multiple items to the cart.

OBS:
Another question. The items should still be in the cart even though I refresh the page, is LocalStorage a good way to make that work?

Here is the ShoppingCart code:

```
const Cart = (props) => {
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);

  let history = useHistory();

  const returnHome = () => history.push("/");

  const { cartItems } = useContext(AddToCartContext); 

  return (
    <StyledApp className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.top}>
        <div className={classes.location}>
          <span>home / shopping cart</span>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.title}>
          <h1>shopping cart</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.grid_container}>
          <Fragment>
            {cartItems === null ? (
              <p>Cart is empty</p>
            ) : (
              <Fragment>
                <Product
                  img={cartItems?.img}
                  name={cartItems?.name}
                  price={cartItems?.price}
                  color={cartItems?.color}
                  id={cartItems?.id}
                />
                <Line></Line>
              </Fragment>
            )}
          </Fragment>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.bottom}>
        <div className={classes.options}>
          <OptionsBox>
            <LeftArrow />
            <span onClick={returnHome} className={classes.options_text}>
              continue shopping
            </span>
          </OptionsBox>
          <OptionsBox>
            <span className={classes.options_text}>clear shopping cart</span>
            <Trash />
          </OptionsBox>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer className={classes.cart_footer}>
        <CartFooter />
      </footer>
    </StyledApp>
  );
};
```

And here is the code for when you add the item (shorten):

```
import { AddToCartContext } from "../../Contexts/AddToCartContext";
const ProductContent = (props) => {
const { setCartItems } = useContext(AddToCartContext);
return (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() =>
                      setCartItems({
                        name: props.name,
                        price: props.price,
                        color: props.mainImg?.colour,
                        img: props.mainImg?.url,
                        id: params.productid,
                      })
                    }
                    className={classes.add_to_cart}
                  >
                    <Cart />
                    add to cart
                  </button>
);
}
```

**Edit**

As requested:

AddToCartContext.js code:

```
import React from "react";

const AddToCartContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AddToCartContext;
```

App.js Code:

```
function App() {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState({});

  return (
    <AddToCartContext.Provider value={{ cartItems, setCartItems }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
        {/* GlobalStyles skapas i ./themes.js */}
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <ShoppingCart theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/category/:type/:id/:productid">
            <FetchAPI />
          </Route>
          //....
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AddToCartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: is `setCartItems` taking care of pushing your new item into an array or is just overriding the current state? I would imagine something like items.push(newItem) going on there as the basic stuff.

Comment: Yes @LuisSardon , `setCartItems` pushes the item. I have used Context API for this.

Comment: Any chance we can see the `AddToCartContext` code?

Comment: Yes of course, I'll edit the post real quick!

Comment: just to be sure, the issue is that you cart only stores one item at a time, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. I need to be able to store multiple items in the cart. Or, multiple items in the `cartItems` which is the useState I have for my context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the old state, try with this:

First you need to set your cartItems default value as an empty array:

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
```

Then persist the state when using `setCartItems`:

```
setCartItems(
  (cartItems) => [
    ...cartItems,
    {
      name: props.name,
      price: props.price,
      color: props.mainImg?.colour,
      img: props.mainImg?.url,
      id: params.productid,
    }
  ]
)
```

Lastly you are rendering just one item when carItems isn't null, you'll have to change that to iterate cartItems instead:

```
<Fragment>
  {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
    <p>Cart is empty</p>
  ) : cartItems.map((item) => (
    <Fragment>
      <Product
        img={item?.img}
        name={item?.name}
        price={item?.price}
        color={item?.color}
        id={item?.id}
      />
      <Line></Line>
    </Fragment>
  ))}
</Fragment>
```

This won't solve for product duplication, but that can be solved at the Cart level, by reducing your cartItems before rendering.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: cartItems is not iterable`. Not even sure what that means?

Comment: yeah, I noticed your default state is an object, so you have to change the default state to be an array (iterable), I just added that as the first step.

Comment: Hmm yes it works, but my google is crashing. It is logging the same product hundreds of times.

Comment: ok, I just found out you're rendering just one element assuming cartItems is an object... let me add a third step, hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: Ahh yes, well the issue I am having at the moment is that my consoled gets spammed with `cartItems`. Here is a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/fb6c79ff559afc5ffde1a898f3a14eca

If I don't remember correctly, `useMemo` can be used here?

Comment: that happens after you click? or from the beginning? can you try changing this `const AddToCartContext = React.createContext([]);` empty array instead of null.

Comment: Also, are you using `cartItems` or `setCartItems` somewhere else?

Comment: This happens whenever I load the product page. 

No, both `cartItems` and `setCartItems` are only used in `App.js`, `ProductContent.js` and `Cart.js`. Haven't used them anywhere else.

Also changed my context to what you said there, but did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232781/discussion-between-simon-sjoo-and-luis-sardon).